# How can I find out what device an op has been assigned to in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm writing distributed Tensorflow code using Jupyter Notebook. I would like to make sure that my operations are placed on the correct devices. I would somehow like to inspect what operations have been assigned to what devices. I know this is possible using Tensorboard, but I was hoping there was a way to do this using Python.

Answer (score 3):

Citing straight from Tensorflow documentation:

> To find out which devices your operations and tensors are assigned to,
>   create the session with log_device_placement configuration option set
>   to True.

```
# Creates a graph.
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

> You should see the following output:

```
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus
id: 0000:05:00.0
b: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
a: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

Comment: Do you know how to do that in tf 2.x?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi [From the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#logging_device_placement) do `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)` anywhere before you start making tensors.

Comment: @MarkPeschel don't hesitate to write it as an answer with some code and I will accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

For Tensorflow 2, to log what devices are being used, use `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)`.

For example, with the following snippet,

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

print(tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

you should get output like

```
2023-06-02 21:03:30.359187: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.

...

input: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2023-06-02 21:03:33.562777: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] input: (_Arg): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
_EagerConst: (_EagerConst): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2023-06-02 21:03:33.562811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] _EagerConst: (_EagerConst): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
output_RetVal: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2023-06-02 21:03:33.562872: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:114] output_RetVal: (_Retval): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2023-06-02 21:03:33.575140: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:1525] Executing op _EagerConst in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2]
 [3 4]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

where the device in use (in this case, `CPU:0`) is printed at the end of each line.

[Link to documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#logging_device_placement)